# CLion support for C++ concepts

Tags: c++, clion, c++-concepts

[Apparently](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/whatsnew/#scope-2020-2-c20) CLion supports concepts now.

However I can't even get the [official example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) to work.

On the `std::convertible...` CLion shows an error `Expected concept name with optional arguments`.

When I try to compile it, it tells me to add the `-fconcepts` flag. When I do that and compile again, I get the error

```
make: concepts: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'concepts'.  Stop.
```

I could't find anyone with a similar issue, just found some tutorials on how to get it to work with earlier versions of CLion, which - as far as I can see - don't apply here.

I'm using CLion 2020.2 Build #CL-202.6397.106, built on July 28, 2020, which should be the newest one. At least I don't see any updates.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: i cannot help much on the issue, but I have one more hint. cppreference usually does follow very closely the official documents, but afaik the code you found is not "the official" example. In any case it would be better if you included the example code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run the cppreference example with CLion 2020.2. The problem why it wasn't working initially for me was that the gcc compiler on my system (Ubuntu 20.04)  was too old (9.2). I tried with the packaged g++10, but that still didn't work, so I had to compiler gcc-10.2 directly from the git sources. That finally made it work.

Also make sure you add `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)` to your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: It was the compiler version for me too. I had 9.3. However I didn't have to get it from the git sources, I just followed the guide here (without multiple versions, just got the ppa from there): https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/#installing-multiple-gcc-versions

Comment: Interseting, I did that first, too. But this installed only gcc 10.0 which seemed to be not able to compile that example. Or perhaps I've messed something up.